# mysql datadir from old hard drive system does not boot

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, fedora

I´m trying to migrate a mysql database from an old drive which had fedora9 (which did not boot anymore) to an ubuntu 16.04 server.

I copied the /var/lib/mysql folder from the old system to /testdb/mysql in the new system.

I change the owner to mysql:mysql to the new folder and update datadir of my.conf to this new folder, but the mysql server does not boot anymore. I get the following error:

```
170625 12:44:37 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
170625 12:44:37 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
170625 12:44:37 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
170625 12:44:37 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170625 12:44:37 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170625 12:44:37 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
170625 12:44:37 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170625 12:44:37 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170625 12:44:37 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170625 12:44:37  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
170625 12:44:38 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
170625 12:44:38 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
170625 12:44:38 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
170625 12:44:38 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170625 12:44:38 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170625 12:44:38 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
170625 12:44:38 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170625 12:44:38 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170625 12:44:38 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170625 12:44:38  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
170625 12:44:38 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
170625 12:44:38 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
170625 12:44:38 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
170625 12:44:38 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170625 12:44:38 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170625 12:44:38 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
170625 12:44:38 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170625 12:44:38 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170625 12:44:38 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170625 12:44:38  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

I tried to change all permissions, even 777 to all files (only to try it), but always have the same result.

How can I recover the databases?

Comment: @BK435 As I put in the question, my first step after copy the folder, was change the owner to mysql:mysql (sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /testdb/mysql). As this first change does not work, I tried to change all permissions to 777 (keeping mysql as user and group)

Comment: Here the ibdata file user and permissions: `-rwxrwxrwx  1 mysql mysql 18874368 jun 25 12:22 ibdata1`

Comment: New test, I had the default folder working fine with a test database on `/var/lib/mysql` then I have created a new folder `sudo mkdir /var/liv` which has user and group `root:root` as the `/var/lib` folder, then I have copied the folder mysql to this new folder (keeping user, group and permissions) `sudo cp -rp /var/lib/mysql /var/liv` and I changed the datadir directory in my.cnf from `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to `datadir = /var/liv/mysql` then the mysql didn´t start anymore (Then, I suppose than the folder is changed correctly, but something fails)

Comment: I don't really know why it happens, but I found a way to recover all tables, I will answer my own question  to mark it as solved, then can help someone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the way to recover the tables, and it is not changing the datadir from my.conf (it didn´t work, even copying the content of the default database that works fine), I copied the folder I want to recover to the default datadir, overwriting all files except mysql.sock and mysql folder.
Then I started the mysql server and it works, but some tables shall to be repaired with

```
mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases -u root -p
```

Now everything works fine